# REST call in AngularJS does not display record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

This is my first AngularJS project. I followed [this website](http://coder1.com/articles/consuming-rest-services-angularjs) to create a simple html to display a single record by calling restful services. The rest works with the url "http://localhost:8080/api/seqs/fdebfd6e-d046-4192-8b97-ac9f65dc2009".
[image]

Here is my html:

```
<html ng-app="cgApp" ng-controller="CgseqCtrl">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <hr>
            <h2>{{seq.analysisId}}</h2>
            <h2>{{seq.library}}</h2>
        </hr>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I defined the resource in a service js

```
//service.js
angular.module('cgApp', ['ngResource'])
.factory('CgseqService', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/seqs/fdebfd6e-d046-4192-8b97-ac9f65dc2009',
            {get: {method: 'GET'}
        });
});
```

The controller:

```
//controller.js
angular.module('cgApp', ['ngResource'])
.controller('CgseqCtrl', ['CgseqService', '$scope', function (CgseqService, $scope)
{
    $scope.getSeq = function(response) {
        CgseqService.get(function(data) {
            $scope.seq = data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

When I started my http server with Node.js and typed the url in the browser, nothing is displayed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where's your success function for the http request?

Comment: `np-controller="CgseqCtrl"`. Typo? Should say `ng-controller`.

Comment: I also don't see where you've imported your factory code in your HTML. It only looks like you loaded your controller code.

Comment: @ggderas The example in the link does not have success/error function in the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors.

You didn't load your factory code. It looks like you only loaded your `controller.js` (I'm assuming your factory code is in a different file since in your example you commented it as `//service.js`):

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
```

`np-controller` should say `ng-controller`:

```
<html ng-app="cgApp" np-controller="CgseqCtrl">
```

You also never called your `$scope.getSeq` function:

```
$scope.getSeq = function(response) {
    CgseqService.get(function(data) {
        $scope.seq = data;
    });
};
```

You should call `$scope.getSeq()` somewhere to actually invoke it.

Comment: I thought the service is declared in controller.js as its dependency. Do I have to list all scripts in that section explicitly?

Comment: @Nasreddin Yeah you need to actually load all your scripts otherwise the code is unaware that the injected dependency `'CgseqService'` even exists.

Comment: Why do I need to call getSeq function? Doesn't the whole controller function get executed?

Comment: @Nasreddin the controller function gets executed, but not necessarily the contents inside of it.

Comment: I can't think of where and how to invoke getSeq. Can I remove the function declaration but expose `CgseqService.get(function(data)` in the controller?

Comment: Just call $scope.getSeq() right after you define it.

Comment: After I did what you suggested, I debugged it in Batarang. It did not even go into controller function at all due to error `Argument 'CgseqCtrl' is not a function, got string`. What's that supposed to mean?